# import content types from sql dump

Tags: 7, database

I recently had a db crash on the site I am currently working on.  I was running sqlite, and the crash locked the db.  No matter what I tried, I couldn't get drupal to access the database again (killed the process, exported into a new db, reinstalled drupal).  So I decided to just migrate it to MySQL.  I converted the sql dump from the old database to MySQL syntax without too many problems.  I can import my nodes just fine, I cannot however get my content types, panels and views to import.

I have tried dbtng migrate, it recognizes both databases, however it keeps giving me schema errors that I can't get around.  ie. destination database does not contain table variable_store -> import variable store from sql dump -> destination database contains table varaible_store dbtng migrate cannot overwrite table.  That is an issue in and of itself, but I digress.

The original site is completely dead, there is no way I can backup from the Drupal UI.

TLDR
cannot import content types, panels or views from sql dump.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your SQLite dump is complete, your best bet is probably to try and properly convert it to MySQL format and then restore to an empty database.

There's a good thread over at stackoverflow with information on SQLite to MySQL conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql

I would paste a solution from there here, but as it's a sibling site, probably ok to just pop over and try some of those solutions.

Good luck

Comment: Tried restoring to an empty database, no dice.  Tried installing drupal, then appending the clean install, no dice.  tried installing drupal, removing the inserts from the dump, importing, letting the site try to rebuild itself, then importing the data, no dice.  tried installing drupal, installing all the modules and themes, then importing only the content... no dice.

Comment: the issue isn't the syntax, the dump will go into an empty database without any issues.

Comment: "*the dump will go into an empty database without any issues*" - If it successfully restores to an empty database, then that should be sufficient, no?

Comment: No, drupal recognizes the content, but does not any of the associations.  IE, content types are there, but empty, nodes are not assoicated with content types.. etc.  The association data is in the database, but I suspect it's hashed in such a way that it can't just be imported via sql.